# Auto-complete Textfield in titanium ios & Android

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator-mobile, autocompletebox

I want autocomplete textbox like if i press a it should shows related words like apple,aeroplane etc.,i want to make like similar google search.is there any control like this operation in ios and android on titanium.Help with examples codes or it's not possible in titanium?

Comment: check this [example](http://www.redsunsoft.com/2011/02/remote-table-search-with-titanium-appcelerator/)

Comment: you can use tableview and after listed below textfield?

Comment: ok i am searched after link send with you ok...!

Comment: Try this link from tkanzakic http://www.redsunsoft.com/2011/02/remote-table-search-with-titanium-appcelerator/

Comment: if u any doubt comment me ok!

Answer (score 3):

The following code will work for you. Try it and modify as per your need. Here I Used array(searchArray) as data storage(You can replace it with database field or source whatever as per your requirement).

```
//Table view showing your autocomplete values
var tblvAutoComplete = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    width           : '100%',
    backgroundColor : '#EFEFEF',
    height          : 0,
    maxRowHeight    : 35,
    minRowHeight    : 35,
    allowSelection  : true
});
//Starts auto complete
txtAutoComplete.addEventListener('change', function(e){ 
    var pattern = e.source.value;
    var tempArray = PatternMatch(searchArray, pattern);
    CreateAutoCompleteList(tempArray);
});
//You got the required value and you clicks the word
tblvAutoComplete.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    txtAutoComplete.value = e.rowData.result; 
});

//Returns the array which contains a match with the pattern
function PatternMatch(arrayToSearch, pattern){
    var searchLen = pattern.length;
    arrayToSearch.sort();
    var tempArray = [];
    for(var index = 0, len = arrayToSearch.length; index< len; index++){
        if(arrayToSearch[index].substring(0,searchLen).toUpperCase() === pattern.toUpperCase()){
            tempArray.push(arrayToSearch[index]);
        }
    }
    return tempArray;
}
//setting the tableview values
function CreateAutoCompleteList(searchResults){
    var tableData = [];
    for(var index=0, len = searchResults.length; index < len; index++){

            var lblSearchResult = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                top            : 2,
                width          : '40%',
                height         : 34,
                left           : '5%',
                font           : { fontSize : 14 },
                color          : '#000000',
                text           : searchResults[index]
            });

            //Creating the table view row
            var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
               backgroundColor : 'transparent',
               focusable       : true,
               height          : 50,
               result          : searchResults[index]
            });

            row.add(lblSearchResult);
            tableData.push(row);
    }
    tblvAutoComplete.setData(tableData);
    tblvAutoComplete.height = tableData.length * 35;
}
```

This code worked for me in both ios and android. Hope your problems get resolved:D

Comment: Worked like a Charm :D

Answer (score 3):

cool i can give some example for you with android auto address suggestion bar

```
var search = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
 height : '40sp',
        hintText : 'Search',
        top : '3sp',
        right : '0%',
        width : '73%',
        textAlign : 'left',
        font : {

            fontFamily : 'Verdana',
            fontSize : '13sp',

        },
    });
```

your result dispaly as table row

```
var resulttable = Ti.UI.createTableView({
        top : '0%',
        left : '0%',
        width : '100%',
        height : '100%',
        separatorColor : '#000000',

    });
```

and add event listner as change and any change call function with your value and if value is empty remove table from your view

```
search.addEventListener("change", function(event, type) {
        Titanium.API.info("in change event listener");
        if ('' != search.value) {
            tabgroupContentView.add(resulttable);
            if (resulttable.data.length > 0) {
                for (var i = resulttable.data[0].rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    resulttable.deleteRow(i);
                }
            }
            auto_complete(search.value);
        } else {
            tabgroupContentView.remove(resulttable);
        }
    });
```

call following function to auto complte

```
function auto_complete(search_term) {

        loader.open("GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=" + search_term + "&types=geocode&language=en&sensor=true&key=bar blar blar this is my key use ur one");

        loader.onload = function() {

            var histryresult = eval('(' + this.responseText + ')');
            jsonArry = histryresult.predictions;
            jsonArryterms = histryresult.terms;
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonArry.length; i++) {

                var service_row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                    height : '70sp',
                    width : '100%',
                    backgroundColor : '#ffffff',
                    backgroundFocusedColor : '#FF8F2F',
                    backgroundSelectedColor : '#FF8F2F',
                    hasChild : false
                });

                var lbl_oderid = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                    left : '3%',
                    top : '10%',
                    text : jsonArry[i].terms[1].value,
                    color : '#A70CAF',
                    font : {
                        fontSize : '17sp',
                        fontWeight : 'bold'
                    },
                    height : 'auto',
                    width : 'auto'
                });

                var descriptiontext;
                if (jsonArry[i].description == undefined) {
                    descriptiontext = 'Not Valable';
                } else {
                    descriptiontext = jsonArry[i].description;
                }

                var lbl_description = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                    left : '5%',
                    top : '50%',
                    text : descriptiontext,
                    color : '#000000',
                    font : {
                        fontSize : '12sp',

                    },
                    height : 'auto',
                    width : 'auto'
                });

                service_row.add(lbl_oderid);
                service_row.add(lbl_description);
                service_row.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

                    var locaName = jsonArry[e.index].description;

                    if (jsonArry[e.index].description == undefined) {

                    } else {
                        reversGeoloader.open("GET", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + locaName + "&sensor=false");

                        reversGeoloader.onload = function() {

                            var geoResult = eval('(' + this.responseText + ')');
                            jsonArry = geoResult.results;

                            var newlat = jsonArry[0].geometry.location.lat;
                            var newlng = jsonArry[0].geometry.location.lng;

                            curentlatitude = newlat;
                            curentlongitude = newlng;

                            getReversGeo(curentlatitude, curentlongitude, 'str');
                            usercurentlocation.setText('Set by serch');
                            tabTestWindow.close();

                        };
                        reversGeoloader.send();
                    }

                });

                resulttable.appendRow(service_row);

            }

        };
        loader.send();

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
textField.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    // you can fill a tableView in this event with the suggested data
});
```

or this tutorial link might solve your problem
[AutoCompleteTextField](http://www.redsunsoft.com/2011/02/remote-table-search-with-titanium-appcelerator/)